# FEM Global coordinate system of a quadrilateral element

Tags: geometry, finite-element-method

*If this is the wrong community for this question, please let me know.*

Say I have a 4 noded quadrilateral element: [Quad element in NX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSgSz.png)

*(I can't add an embedded image yet...)*

I know the global coordinates of each node **G1** through **G4**.

My idea was the following:

- Find the intersection of the two diagonals = **D**
- Find the angle **alpha**
- Find the intersection point between **Axis X** and edge **G2-G3** = **G23**
- Global direction of local **Axis X** = **G23** - **D**

The problem is that for a quad element, the nodes are not necessarily on the same plane. Therefor, the global coordinates of the location of the element's local coordinate system is not *exactly* at the intersection of the two diagonals.

Assuming all the nodes are on the same plane, the intersection of the diagonals would be trivial.

A general rule in FEM is that quad elements *should* be as flat as possible. But how does a FEM solver usually *flatten* a non-flat element, or how does it define the global position of the element's local coordinate system?

Comment: Usually in FEM you start by defining a local coordinate system for a square reference quadrilateral (which is always flat according to your definition) and then try to come up with a mapping which maps the flat reference quadrilateral into your (possibly non-flat) global quadrilateral. Then you can use the mapping and its inverse to move points between the two representations. All integration etc. calculations are usually done in the reference quadrilateral. So you don't really need the kind of coordinate system as depicted in your figure. Can you elaborate what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean. So for my case I'm interested in knowing if there is a _standard_ method of doing the _mapping which maps the flat reference quadrilateral into your (possibly non-flat) global quadrilateral_. Basically I want to know what is the direction of an elements x-axis in the _gobal_ coordinate system.

Comment: To elaborate. I'm reading analysis files in which I have the node coordinates of the elements, and I have analysis results which are defined by the elements axes. I also have strain gage results, their orientations are defined in the global coordinate system of the FEM model. So all this has to do with reading this information and compare results correctly.

Comment: Typically we use so-called isoparametric mappings that are defined by the basis functions of the element. The resulting mapping is not affine in general. This means that if you map the local x-axis into the global coordinate system, the resulting "axis" might not be a straight line (it can be curved). I can add more information on this later if you are interested.

Comment: Interesting.. I could imagine such a mapping for 2nd order quad elements, but not for linear. Yes please add some info or possibly a link to details on this.

Comment: I might add that having done some work with commercial FEM software, I know that it can be very hard to deduce how the strains are actually calculated in a given software. The most typical approach to solid mechanics FEM is to solve only displacements and then post process strains. Nevertheless, there are still multiple 'equally good' ways to compute strains from the displacements that give slightly different results.

Comment: Yes in my case here, _how_ the FEM solver has calculated the strains doesn't really matter, just which direction the strain is calculated for. Anyway, I might be going a little bit too deep in the details here, more than I need. But always nice to learn more:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It seems that I made a small mistake in the comment claiming that for a bilinear basis the resulting axes can be curved. It seems that this is not the case although it initially did not feel very intuitive to me. Let me try to explain this and how isoparametric mappings work.*

Suppose we have the reference quadrilateral $D = \{(X,Y) : -1 < X < -1, -1 < Y < 1\}$. The bilinear basis functions on this domain are
$$\varphi_1 = \frac14(1-X)(1-Y),\\ \varphi_2 = \frac14(1-X)(1+Y),\\ \varphi_3 = \frac14(1+X)(1+Y),\\\varphi_4 = \frac14(1+X)(1-Y).$$
The basis functions are visualized in the following figure.
[image]

The isoparametric mapping from $D$ to arbitrary quadrilateral embedded in 3D space is
$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix} = F(X,Y) = \sum_{j=1}^4 \begin{pmatrix} x_j\\y_j\\z_j \end{pmatrix} \varphi_j(X,Y)$$
where $(x_j,y_j,z_j),~j\in\{1,2,3,4\},$ are the locations of the corner nodes in the global coordinate system. We can now visualize the surface $F(D)$ that results from mapping the domain $D$ through $F$ with the example corner locations
$$(x_1,y_1,z_1) = (-1,0,0),\\(x_2,y_2,z_2) = (0,1,1),\\(x_3,y_3,z_3) = (1,1,0),\\(x_4,y_4,z_4) = (3/2,-1,1).$$
[image]

As you can see, the resulting quadrilateral can have a quite wonky shape. Not flat at all! This is why I assumed that if we mapped the axes through $F$ (i.e. compute the sets $F(\{(x,y) : x=0\})$ and $F(\{(x,y) : y=0)$) they could also look curved.

Then I tried doing exactly that and it was revealed that what we get are always straight lines indeed (the blue lines correspond to mapped axes):

[image]

[image]

I should have figured this out since the bilinear functions are linear exactly in the direction of the local axes.

**In conclusion,** I think that the best way to find these local axes is to map points through the mapping $F$.

Comment: Well presented answer, thank you! I will go through this when i have time to _digest_ it:).

Comment: Ah, now I completely agree with your answer!